# jquery mobile select onclose event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a filter function implemented on "panel" in *jQuery Mobile*:

- I call filter by clicking on any button, the panel slides from left and there are filter options to set up current filter.
- If multiple select box contains a lot of options, it shows on a black background covering the whole page and it closes the panel.

I need to reopen the panel with filter after this dialog of multi-select is closed...

I am using this:

```
$('#filter select').bind('change',function(){
    $('#filter').panel('open');
});
```

This is OK if the user does any change in opened dialog (select)...
But what if he just closes this dialog using the X-button without any change? Dialog disappears, but panel is not reopened.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile custom *selectmenu* are either converted into *popup* or a *dialog* depending on screen size and options length.

When the *selectmenu* is dialog, it navigates to a new dialog-page. In that case, you can listen to *pagecontainer events* to retrieve previous `prevPage` and next page `toPage`.

If previous page is a dialog/selectmenu, open panel in next page.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, data) {
    var previousPage = data.prevPage,
        nextPage = data.toPage;
    if (previousPage.hasClass("ui-selectmenu")) { /* or ui-dialog */
        $(".ui-panel", nextPage).panel("open");
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0q5w6y1gJS3fB3ImAwk?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm using JQM 1.3.2, and I've found, that pagecontainershow is available since 1.4.1 - so I've used "pageshow" instead. Then this works perfect!

Comment: @user1846815 you're welcome. I do recommend using jQM 1.4.4, soon 1.3 will be obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: I agree - this is "older" project and there are some incompatible places on changing from 1.3.x to 1.4.x - so I am waiting with this for some good chance... But I know, that I have to change this. Thank you!