# JQM non-native selectmenu close callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i need onclose trigger event on dialog which opens when clickng on selectmenu.

selectmenu got `data-native-menu="false"` so it opens list popup (dialog/page depending on how long list is).

But there is [no event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/) for closing, so how would you trigger event when that dialog closes?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you really looking to catch when the popup/dialog closes, or is the change event on the select good enough?

Comment: Popup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26698451/1771795 dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26673431/1771795

Comment: @ezanker change is not enough for me, I have long list with multiple choices and after that I need to do quite heavy recalculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Popup

Listen to `popupafterclose` to custom selectmenu. The popup inherits the ID of selectmenu plus *-listbox* added to it. Since its dynamically generated, you need to delegate the listener.

```
$("parentPageID").on("popupafterclose", "#selectmenuID-listbox", function () {
   /* do something */
});
```

#### Dialog

Dialogs like pages, they use *pagecontainer* events. Listen to `pagecomtainerhide` and check if that page/dialog has `.ui-selectmenu` class. *pagecontainer* events can't be attached directly nor can be delegated.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, data) {
   if ( data.prevPage.hasClass("ui-selectmenu") ) {
      /* do something */
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, although it's not exactly clean solution. There should be close callback.

Comment: @user76329 you can request from JQM team to add this feature in future version.